# I keep getting this Solidity compiler error, so how do I fix it?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Here is the relevant code. I cannot figure out why it is getting a parse error, the onlyOwner modifier looks correct to me:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

// Fractional Real Estate Protocol
contract FractionalRealEstate {
    struct Asset {
        address owner;
        string description;
        uint256 totalShares;
        uint256 pricePerShare;
    }
    
    struct Order {
        address orderOwner;
        uint256 assetId;
        uint256 shareCount;
    }
    
    mapping(uint256 => Asset) public assets;
    mapping(uint256 => Order[]) public buyOrders;
    mapping(uint256 => Order[]) public sellOrders;
    uint256 public assetCount;

    ERC20 public token;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed; // Chainlink price feed contract
    
    // Events
    event RegisterAsset(string description, uint256 price, uint256 shares);
    event SetAssetPrice(uint256 assetId, uint256 newPrice);
    
    constructor(address _tokenAddress, address _priceFeed) {
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
        owner = msg.sender;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }
    
    function registerAsset(string description, uint256 price, uint256 shares) external onlyOwner {
        require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0.");
        assetCount++;
        assets[assetCount] = Asset(msg.sender, description, price, shares);
        
        emit RegisterAsset(description, price, shares);
    }
    
    function setAssetPrice(uint256 assetId, uint256 newPrice) external onlyOwner {
        require(assetId > 0 && assetId <= assetCount, "Invalid asset ID.");
        Asset storage asset = assets[assetId];
        require(asset.owner != address(0), "Asset does not exist.");
        asset.price = newPrice;
        
        emit SetAssetPrice(assetId, newPrice);
    }
```

Here is the compiler error:

## Compiling your contracts...

> Compiling ./contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol

ParserError: Invalid token.
--> project:/contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol:48:1:
|
48 |         require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function.");
| ^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.9.2 (core: 5.9.2)
Node v18.16.0

What is the invalid token? This is the

I tried to compile this Solidity code with the truffle compile command and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

First error:

```
function registerAsset(
    // Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in 
    // string memory description
    external function
        string memory description,
        uint256 price,
        uint256 shares
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0.");
        assetCount++;
        assets[assetCount] = Asset(msg.sender, description, price, shares);
        emit RegisterAsset(description, price, shares);
    }
```

second error:

```
function setAssetPrice(
        uint256 assetId,
        uint256 newPrice
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(assetId > 0 && assetId <= assetCount, "Invalid asset ID.");
        Asset storage asset = assets[assetId];
        require(asset.owner != address(0), "Asset does not exist.");
        // you have pricePerShare field, not price
        // asset.price = newPrice;
        asset.pricePerShare = newPrice;

        emit SetAssetPrice(assetId, newPrice);
    }
}
```